# Google Analytics alternatives to get raw data

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, event-tracking

I have problem with finding a service which can be alternative to Google Analytics.

Scenario: My company is using Firebase Analytics to track events from our apps. Everyday, these apps can generate over 30-40 million event tracking logs for each app and send it to Google Analytics. After that, these tracking data will be transferred to Big Query, which can be used for ETL transformation later.

Problem: According to Google's policy, the event tracking data for each app cannot exceed 1 million per day. This consequently leads to the case that the data can not be transferred to Big Query to perform transformation. In order to get more RAW data per day, we need to upgrade our service to Premium version (Google Analytics 360). However, the cost of this is quite large and exceeds the budget of our entrepreneur. Google still support their customers to get data through API but it only allows to get aggregated data, not the original counterparts.
So we are finding an alternative to Google Analytics which allows to get RAW data and transfer it to our data warehouse.

I really need your help to give me sound advice on which service can be replaced Google Analytics in this case which is more cost-effective and adapt the requirements above

Answer (score 0):

Well there are open-source solutions like [Matomo](https://matomo.org/). But you have to host it, along with its endpoints to which you send the data. You will end up spending quite a bit on the rent of an infrastructure that can swallow that volume of data. You will also spend quite a number of hours figuring it out from scratch.

There's also Adobe Analytics, which has much more flexible pricing, but it's more for enterprises whose needs aren't covered by GA 360 since Adobe offers a way more powerful analytics solution. Also, Adobe experts are more expensive than GA ones.

You can also consider streaming your events directly to your BQ, preserving the data structure your GA exports have. That might be easier. And BQ doesn't charge much for inserting the data. But you certainly should check what the charge would be for your volume of insertions.

Finally, the real answer here is to reduce the volume of events. With the volume you have, and given how you can't (or can, but don't want to) afford 360 with this volume, you're likely either over-tracking or you have basic architectural problems with your tracking infrastructure. There are often many wasteful mistakes done in app tracking, especially when it's not governed by analytics experts. A tracking task easily solvable with one event and two custom dimensions (event properties) would often be implemented by developers using tens of events. Devs would often disregard cases when the same event is sent multiple times in a row, which happens all over the place in apps. Multiply that waste by the members and you get a hugely inflated number of events.

Comment: Is it possible to stream data from Firebase Analytics directly? I think it is only possible to get raw data through Google Analytics

Comment: I believe so too.

Comment: Can you share any docs related to streaming raw data from Firebase Analytics to Big Query if you have?

Comment: Just found this: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#zippy=%2Cin-this-article Never tried it though. Try it out, see if it creates the link for you.

Comment: Thank you for your link. Yet it is the Data transfer approach (Which stream data from Firebase to GA4 to Big Query), which raises the limit of 1M events per day. So I think I need to investigate another way

Comment: Right, Looks like Firebase is what used to be GA4 before GA4. They effectively just took Firebase's backend, made a fancy new UI for it and started calling it GA4. It's the same thing, essentially, data-wise.